# How to sync Calendar Personal With Calendar Sharepoint Online

Tags: outlook, calendar, sharepoint-online

I have the calendar personal on outlook office.

[image]

How to embed it in calendar SharePoint online site?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, syncing personal calendar with SharePoint Online classic calendar list is not available.

As a workaround, you could try to use the group calendar web part.

Reference:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-group-calendar-web-part-eaf3c04d-5699-48cb-8b5e-3caa887d51ce